# Solving 190 equations from a list of 2x20 elements

Tags: equation-solving, data, combinatorics

I have a list of 20 pairs of elements, say `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}`, and I want to solve the following equation for a constant `c` for every possible combination of `{xi, yi}` and `{xj, yj}`:

```
yi(xi + c) == yj(xj + c)
```

and of course I would rather not type

```
Solve[yi(xi + c) == yj(xj +c), c]
```

190 times. I'm still a beginner, so I really have no idea where I should even start or what to even google for this. Does anyone have an Idea?

Comment: Hello, can edit your question and paste the actual 20 pairs of elements. Then we can answer with actual code. Thanks

Comment: Look up `Outer` https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html You want to define your function `f[{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_}]` and you probably want to experiment with the `level n` use of `Outer` so that it only uses your pairs and not every individual number. Does that give you enough of a hint that you can figure this out for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You may write:

```
n = 3; 
vars = Array[{Subscript[y, #], Subscript[x, #]} &, n];
mat = Outer[(#1 + {0, c} == #2 + {0, c}) &, vars, vars, 1];
Join @@ Table[mat[[i, i + 1 ;;]], {i, Length[mat]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Table

```
Table[ Solve[i[[2]] (i[[1]] + c) == j[[2]] (j[[1]] + c), 
            c], {i, {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}}, {j, {{x1, y1}, {x2, 
                    y2}, {x3, y3}}}] // Flatten
```

```
{c -> (-x1 y1 + x2 y2)/(y1 - y2), c -> (-x1 y1 + x3 y3)/(y1 - y3), 
    c -> (-x1 y1 + x2 y2)/(y1 - y2), c -> (-x2 y2 + x3 y3)/(y2 - y3), 
    c -> (-x1 y1 + x3 y3)/(y1 - y3), c -> (-x2 y2 + x3 y3)/(y2 - y3)}
```